# Are there any differences between "understand someone" and "understand about (someone)"?

Tags: phrases, expressions

This book says

> understand someone并没有“理解某人”的意思，只是“懂得某人的话”之意，如：If he had spoken French
> I would not have understood
> him.（要是他说的是法语，我可就不懂他的话了。）汉语中现在常说的“理解万岁”中的“理解”可译成understand about
> (someone)，如：You don't understand about
> me.（你一点也不理解我。）这里理解的不是指所说的话，而是指一个人的心情、做法等。Her parents really understood
> about her situation.（她的父母亲真的理解她的处境。）
>
> ——*翻译辨误(图文版)*

that "understand someone" means "to know the words that someone is saying", like

> If he had spoken French I would not have understood him.

and that "understand about (someone)" means "to know how (someone) feels, behaves and etc.", like

> You don't understand about me.
>
> Her parents really understood about her situation.

But I find many dictionaries say that "understand someone" can mean "to know someone's character, how they feel and why they behave in the way they do", like

> He doesn't understand women at all.
>
> My parents just don’t understand me.

and that "understand about something" means "to know or realize how or why something happens, how it works or why it is important", like

> Doctors still don't understand much about the disease.

So are there any differences between "understand me" and "understand about me"?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The difference is in the scope of the understanding; whereas, "understanding someone" does not specify any given aspect or a domain of the human sphere on which this understanding might bear, "understanding about someone" implies a restriction on those levels: the locutor is not concerned about understanding as a whole. This can be elicited from instances of current usage; however, the two constructions can be used to say the same thing in some cases.

- [1](https://books.google.fr/books?id=_glPAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA66&dq=%22understand+about+him%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjTru21wqTrAhUK1RoKHaIIB44Q6AEwA3oECAAQAg#v=onepage&q=%22understand%20about%20him%22&f=false) And what do you not understand about him?” “For one thing, he carries a gun, which I don't like or understand. Next, he had two f1ghts yesterday with Cowboy, which you and Mother seemed to approve of and which I do not.
- [2](https://books.google.fr/books?id=lrroBgAAQBAJ&pg=PT141&dq=%22understand+about+him%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjTru21wqTrAhUK1RoKHaIIB44Q6AEwBHoECA4QAg#v=onepage&q=%22understand%20about%20him%22&f=false) There were so many things she didn't understand about him.
- [3](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22understand%20about%20him%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en) I'm in love with Ed, but there's a lot I don't understand about him...”
  (*One could have said "I don't understand him a lot".*)
- [4](https://books.google.fr/books?id=hJi032EI_FYC&pg=PA163&dq=%22understand+about+him%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjTru21wqTrAhUK1RoKHaIIB44Q6AEwBnoECCYQAg#v=onepage&q=%22understand%20about%20him%22&f=false) With this wisdom we can understand about Him, about our Father, about what His Power is like. We can know more about His Power.
  (*Note that the concern is to understand more, to know more, not to know wholly.*)
- [5](https://books.google.fr/books?id=ZgJ3Bi76v80C&pg=PA378&dq=%22understand+about+him%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjTru21wqTrAhUK1RoKHaIIB44Q6AEwCHoECC0QAg#v=onepage&q=%22understand%20about%20him%22&f=false) There is a level, a deeper level that God wants us to understand about Him.
- [6](https://books.google.fr/books?id=xxdHAAAAMAAJ&q=%22understand+about+him%22&dq=%22understand+about+him%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjTru21wqTrAhUK1RoKHaIIB44Q6AEwCXoECCsQAg) One way is to understand about him . I read about him , I hear others talk about him , I hear him discussed at staff conferences – I understand about him . I understand him , so to speak , through the eyes of others , not through my own or his.
  (*Finally, understanding*  about *him becomes "understanding him", which is nothing more than a generalizing statement.*)
- [7](https://books.google.fr/books?id=e1caYCGMI9UC&pg=PT89&dq=%22understand+about+him%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjTru21wqTrAhUK1RoKHaIIB44Q6AEwDXoECDcQAg#v=onepage&q=%22understand%20about%20him%22&f=false) But there is something I don't quite understand about him. Something enigmatic, as if he is operating behind a mask.” “That's because he's an Arab,” said Hoffman. “These people are born with masks on.”
  (*Note that "don't understand something … about him" is more specific than "I don't understand him", which would be an overstatement once the locutor reveals it is question of nothing else but the character's attitude.*)
- [8](https://books.google.fr/books?id=x4pgkd4QLYAC&pg=PA149&dq=%22understand+about+him%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjTru21wqTrAhUK1RoKHaIIB44Q6AEwEnoECD8QAg#v=onepage&q=%22understand%20about%20him%22&f=false) But the more we understand about him, the better our chance of catching him be— comes.”
  (*Here, "But the more we understand him," would have done as well since the state of understanding is made partial by the adverb "more".*)
- [9](https://books.google.fr/books?id=1f3MZcPAnDoC&pg=PT19&dq=%22understand+about+him%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjTru21wqTrAhUK1RoKHaIIB44Q6AEwHHoECE8QAg#v=onepage&q=%22understand%20about%20him%22&f=false) He expects me to do penance for things I will never begin to know or understand about him.